# Non-optional property of optional struct being shown as optional

Tags: swift, xcode, option-type

Town struct:

```
struct Town {
    var population: Int = 5_422
    var numberOfStoplights: Int = 4

    func printDescription() {
        print("The town has \(population) people and \(numberOfStoplights) stoplights")
    }

    mutating func changePopulation(by amount: Int) {
        population += amount
    }
}
```

Monster class:

```
class Monster {
    var town: Town?
    var name = "Monster"

    func terrorizeTown() {
        if town != nil {
            print("\(name) is terrorizing a town")
        } else {
            print("\(name) hasn't found a town to terrorize yet")
        }
    }
}
```

Zombie class:

```
class Zombie: Monster {
    var walksWithLimp = true

    final override func terrorizeTown() {

        if town?.population > 0 {
            town?.changePopulation(by: -10)
        }

        super.terrorizeTown()
    }
}
```

I'm getting a compiler error on `town?.population` saying 'value of optional Int not unwrapped...'. I haven't declared `population` to be an optional and if I change this to `town?.population?` it says population is a non-optional Int. Both these errors contradict each other, what's going on?

Comment: But town is....

Comment: read about optional chain (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html) - you have very short one here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Optional chaining, even when querying non-optional methods and properties, will yield a result that is an optional

Consider the following example:

```
struct Foo {
    let bar: Int // not: not an optional
    init(_ bar: Int) { self.bar = bar }
}

let foo: Foo? = Foo(42) // 'foo' is an optional
```

In case we are not interested particularly in `foo`, but rather specifically in its member `bar`, we may use [optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html) to query access to `bar` of `foo`, which will give us the value of `bar` wrapped in `.some(...)` in case `foo` is not `nil`, and `nil` otherwise. I.e., such a query (even to a non-optional property as `bar) will yield an optional:

```
let optBar = foo?.bar // this is now an optional (Optional<Int>)
```

> To reflect the fact that optional chaining can be called on a `nil`
>   value, **the result of an optional chaining call is always an optional
>   value**, even if the property, method, or subscript you are querying
>   returns a nonoptional value.

Before we proceed, we also note that in Swift 3 we may no longer compare optional operands by the `Comparable` operators, as stated in the following accepted and implemented Swift evolution proposal:

- [Remove Optional Comparison Operators](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0121-remove-optional-comparison-operators.md)

Hence, if you'd like to conditionally proceed into an `if` block given the following:

- `foo` is not `nil`, and
- if so, `bar` is larger than `0`

Then you first need to, in some manner, achieve a concrete value of (the possibly existing) `bar` prior to comparing it to `0`.

You can do this e.g. a combined optional binding and boolean conditional `if` statement:

```
if let nonOptionalBar = foo?.bar, nonOptionalBar > 0 {
    print("'foo' is not nil and its 'bar' member is larger than 0")
} // prints "'foo' is not nil and its 'bar' member is larger than 0"
```

If you don't plan to use the value `bar`, however (and only wants to decrease it's population), you could make use of the [`nil` coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html) to construct a conditional `if` statement that will fail given that `foo` is `nil` or its member `bar` is not greater than 0:

```
if (foo?.bar ?? -1) > 0 {
    print("'foo' is not nil and its 'bar' member is larger than 0")
}
```

Here, `(foo?.bar ?? -1)` will result in `-1` if `foo` is `nil` (which will subsequently result in `false` for `-1 > 0`), or result in the value of `bar` (as a non-optional concrete `Int`) in case `foo` is not `nil`.

We could also make use of the [`map` method of `Optional`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/optional/1539476-map) to conditionally (that `foo` is not `nil`) test the comparison, and if `foo` is `nil`, supply `false` as a default value using the `nil` coalescing operator on the return from the call to `map`.

```
if foo.map({ $0.bar > 0 }) ?? false {
    print("'foo' is not nil and its 'bar' member is larger than 0")
}
```

The three alternatives applied to your example:

```
if let population = town?.population, population > 0 {
    town?.changePopulation(by: -10)
}

if (town?.population ?? -1) > 0 {
    town?.changePopulation(by: -10)
}

if town.map({ $0.population > 0 }) ?? false {
    town?.changePopulation(by: -10)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression returns an optional `Int` but you are still testing it using non-optional syntax. You need to use `if let`.

```
if let pop = town?.population {
    if pop > 0
```

etc.

The optional chain does not remove the optionality. It simply cascades it so that any nil in the chain causes a nil to pop out at the end. But the result is still optional.

Answer (score 0):

Because town?.population is still Int?, and you can't compare Int? with Int unless you get the Int from Int?

So the code could be

```
if let town = town, town.population > 0 {
    town.changePopulation(by: -10)
}
super.terrorizeTown()
```

Comment: This approach contains two issues: **1)** `town` is value type `Struct`, so this will only _copy_ the `town` instance in the optional binding (to an _immutable_ `Town` instance named `town`), thereafter attempt to _mutate_ this immutable copy, which will yield an error. We may "redeem" this error by using `if var town = town, ....`, but then the next issue follows: **2)** since `town` is a value type, the shadowing `town` variable in the `if` block will only be a copy, and any mutations on it will not be reflected in the `town` member instance of the `Zombie` instance.

Answer (score 0):

You must initialise instance of you structure Town, otherwise it is always return nil. So I see your code, Town? is always return nil.